# How to modify the HTTP request headers using Greasemonkey before a new page is loaded?

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I know about the `GM_xmlhttpRequest` api, but it's not what I'm asking about.

For instance, I want to visit Stack Overflow with a new UA(user-agent), can I do it with a Greasemonkey script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey only fire *after* the initial page request is made.
**They cannot alter the user-agent.**

Modern browsers let you change the reported user-agent in the settings.  In addition, there are a plethora of extensions that assist in changing the UA.
(Or you can write your own extension.)

Search *Superuser* for more information.  Here's [**a list of likely Q&As there**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-agent?sort=votes&pageSize=50&mixed=1).